# Register user with same email with different provider when email already registered throws no error

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular7, firebaseui

Ive registered a user with google oauth. When i try to use the same email to register a microsoft user, i get endless loading screen. Im first redirected to the provider to sign in with provider credentials. Im then redirected back to my app. No error is thrown, im simply redirected to the main login page and firebaseui widget shows endless loading bar.

[endlessloading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nYa8.png)

Ive tried the demo from firebasui github and it performs as expected. When i register with the same email, an error pops up asking me to log in with my google account. In my application im using  firebasui angular wrapper firebaseui-wrapper. I tried using only firebaseui without the wrapper but the result was the same. Im listening to authstatechanges but no authstate changes are emitted. Probably because user is not authenticated in the app. firebaseui exposes to eventemitters signInSuccessWithAuthResult and signInFailure. None of them emit any errors or results.

No error is thrown when i try to register user email that is already registered with google provider in my app, with microsoft provider. Firebaseui widget is expected to show a notification in the widget that says that the user is already exits

My signinoptions from firebasui module

```
 signInFlow: 'popup',
 signInOptions: [
 auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
 {
  buttonColor:"#000000",
  iconUrl: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active- 
  directory/develop/media/howto-add-branding-in-azure-ad-apps/ms- 
  symbollockup_mssymbol_19.png",
  provider:    new auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com').providerId,
  providerName: "Microsoft",
  customParameters:{
    tenant: 'myspace.com'
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you inspect the browser console. There are probably errors there that will shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Was hoping for that but there r none....

Comment: Did you check for network request errors? Do you notice any anomaly (non-200 responses) there?

Answer (score 0):

firebaseui is a crap library at least for Angular in my opinion. I made my one.

- My library is responsible only to manage user authentication.
- You can pick how to display login panel.
- Added possibility to manage/translate errors but you have to make your own service. In your service, implement `AuthErrorHandler` and in module switch `AuthErrorHandlerService` to your new service. In the future will try to do something with it.
- Inside repository You have 'auth-test' folder example app. To display panel I'm using `@angular/material`.

**Repository git:**
https://bitbucket.org/mises543/fire-ngx-auth

**npm:**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fire-ngx/auth